# Vuex separate file getters.js and getter with argument

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have separate file getters.js:

```
export const getDate = (state, format) => {
    const getDateFormat = (state, format) => {
        return moment(state.date).format(format)
    }
    return getDateFormat(state, format)
}
```

I using this method `getDate` inside component:

```
computed:{
    ...mapGetters({
        getDate: 'getDate',
    }),
    getDateFormat() {
        return this.getDate('dd-mm-yyyy')
    },
},
```

but Vue return me error:

> this.getDate is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fix it, I change my method to arrow function:

```
export const getDate = state => format => {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass custom arguments to getter. The arguments of getter:

> state, getters, rootState

```
 getItem(state, getters, rootState) {

 }
```

Comment: ok, I change, now my function looks like this:
```export const getDate = state => {
    const getDateFormat = format => {
        //...
    }
    return getDateFormat()
}```
But still I have this same error.